# google maps api v3 not displaying

Tags: php, html, google-maps

i want to display google map in my webpage,but it is not displaying in my webpage,i cant fix what the error is,i tried diffrent methods but still map area is looking blank...so please help me to fix the error....sorry for my english

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyA39kFEuPToMAHcpdQzzpZFmpyENv9MT_A&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post" onSubmit="return check_add_form();">
<table width="100%" border="0" class="details">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" align="left" nowrap="nowrap" class="top-heading">Map Location</th>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th width="22%" align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap" class="heading">Address: </th>
    <td width="78%" align="left" valign="top"> <input type="text" id="Location_Address" name="Location_Address" value="<?php echo stripslashes($Location_Address);?>"/>
      <span class="red">*</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
    <input type="hidden" id="Latitude" name="Latitude" value="<?php echo stripslashes($Latitude);?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="Longitude" name="Longitude" value="<?php echo stripslashes($Longitude);?>"/>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <th  nowrap="nowrap"></th><td align="left" valign="top"><span id="message" class="red"><?php echo $message;?></span><br />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</form>
`
```

thanks in advance....

Comment: Have you tried checking the Console in either Chrome or Safari to see if any JavaScript errors are being thrown?

Comment: @MartinBean no errors ,but it is not displaying anything...

Comment: This is a FAQ.  Your map div doesn't have a size. [example with fixed size](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_wontDisplay.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following code in head of the document

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyA39kFEuPToMAHcpdQzzpZFmpyENv9MT_A&sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

and use

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

in any place on your document